# How to get common min and max values from multiple arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, lodash

```
const arrayA = [5.2, 3, 3.5, 2.7, 3.3, 5, 2.9];
const arrayB = [1, 2.2, 7, 3, 3.2, 2.7, 6.2, 1.9, 3.3, 2, 9]
const arrayC = [2.7, 3, 3.3, 8, 2.7, 5, 1.5, 4]
```

In these arrays, the common min and max values are from that part [image]

How can I get the min and max value in JavaScript or using lodash?

Comment: What should the result be for your provided example, and why? Your question is unclear.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? After you have the common values, finding the min and max is trivial.

Comment: try lodash intersection

Comment: Why isn't this obvious? First get an array of the common elements, then get its min and max

Answer (score 1):

You could take the common values and get min and max value from this set.

```js
const
    arrayA = [5.2, 3, 3.5, 2.7, 3.3, 5, 2.9],
    arrayB = [1, 2.2, 7, 3, 3.2, 2.7, 6.2, 1.9, 3.3, 2, 9],
    arrayC = [2.7, 3, 3.3, 8, 2.7, 5, 1.5, 4],
    common = [arrayA, arrayB, arrayC].reduce((a, b) => a.filter(v => b.includes(v)));

console.log(common);
console.log(Math.min(...common));
console.log(Math.max(...common));
```

Answer (score 1):

Lodash version, using `_.intersection` `_.min` and `_.max` :

```js
const arrayA = [5.2, 3, 3.5, 2.7, 3.3, 5, 2.9];
const arrayB = [1, 2.2, 7, 3, 3.2, 2.7, 6.2, 1.9, 3.3, 2, 9];
const arrayC = [2.7, 3, 3.3, 8, 2.7, 5, 1.5, 4];

const commonVals = _.intersection(arrayA, arrayB, arrayC);

const commonMin = _.min(commonVals);
const commonMax = _.max(commonVals);

console.log("Common min:", commonMin);
console.log("Common max:", commonMax);
console.log("Common vals:", commonVals);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the Math.min and Math.max functions, I provided an altenartive solution. We basically just merge all 3 arrays into one and only keep the common values. hen we find the min and max manually by iterating through the array.

```
const arrayB = [1, 2.2, 7, 3, 3.2, 2.7, 6.2, 1.9, 3.3, 2, 9]
const arrayC = [2.7, 3, 3.3, 8, 2.7, 5, 1.5, 4]

//we combine the arrays and only keep the common values
const commonValues = [arrayA, arrayB, arrayC].reduce((a, b) => a.filter(v => 
b.includes(v)));

let min = Number.MAX_VALUE
let max = Number.MIN_VALUE

for (let i = 0; i < commonValues.length; i++) {
  if (min > commonValues[i]) {
    min = commonValues[i]
  }
  if (max < commonValues[i]) {
    max = commonValues[i]
  }
}

console.log(min) 
console.log(max)
```